# Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am stuck with following error, my stacktrace:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: dao.GenericDaoImpl dao.UserDao.genericDaoImpl; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'genericDaoImpl' defined in file [D:\Juno WorkSpace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\FoodCart\WEB-INF\classes\dao\GenericDaoImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: : No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'genericDaoImpl' defined in file [D:\Juno WorkSpace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\FoodCart\WEB-INF\classes\dao\GenericDaoImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: : No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:730)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:196)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1051)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:955)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:490)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:910)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:853)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:768)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:486)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:986)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:856)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:768)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:795)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:723)
    ... 58 more
Aug 1, 2013 11:39:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet /FoodCart threw load() exception
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:986)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:856)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:768)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:795)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:723)
```

**This is my class GenericDaoImpl.java**

```
package dao;


import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Repository
public class GenericDaoImpl<T> extends HibernateDaoSupport implements GenericDao<T> {


    @Autowired
    public GenericDaoImpl(SessionFactory sessionFactory){
        super.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
    }

    protected void init() {
        //Do Nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void save(T t) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        getHibernateTemplate().save(t);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(T t) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        getHibernateTemplate().update(t);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(T t) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        getHibernateTemplate().delete(t);
    }

}
```

**Following is my springcongif.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">


<context:component-scan base-package="controllers,dao" />


 <bean id="viewResolver"
           class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
           <property name="prefix">
              <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
           </property>
           <property name="suffix">
              <value>.jsp</value>
           </property>
     </bean>

</beans>
```

**And following is my hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory name="SpringConfig">
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">..</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">..</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">..</property>
        <property name="hibernate.default_schema">..</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <mapping class="beans.SampleBean"/>  
        <mapping class="beans.User"/>   
   </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**Please some one point me out, where I am doing mistake. Any help will be appreciated.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is self-explanatory: no Spring bean of type `SessionFactory` is defined. And indeed, there is no bean of type `SessionFactory` defined in `springcongif.xml`.

Read http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#orm-hibernate for how to define a bean of type `SessionFactory`.

Comment: Oh I got it, I did silly mistake I had sort it out, thanks for your time.